# Error when building an android APK in Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk

Might not be an error, maybe it's just me being kinda slow, but once I click on build, on the usual menu, as the image below shows...[image]

Unity asks me to select "something" in my computer, which is weird, it doesn't lets me select a file, or a program, or anything. It's really really weird because I can't select anything. Once I close the window it gives me an error that no Android SDK could be found, also weird since I downloaded it from android's website and installed it properly. What could it be?

Comment: Since error says 'no android sdk found', make sure your android sdk path is set in unity3d or do it by selecting Unity > Preferences from the menu and then clicking on External Tools in the preferences window.

Comment: But then, what should I select in the preferences window? It doesn't lets me select the Android Studio app

Comment: No worries guys, I solved it, thanks for your replies! <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you installed the Android Studio is easier to set up.

On Android Studio, follow these steps:

Tools > Android > SDK Manager

[image]

Now at new window copy the address from which this SDK (Android SDK location)

[image]

At unity go to:

Edit > preferences

[image]

At new windown (Unity preferences) go to `tab` `External Tools`

Paste andress from SDK location at the SDK place

[image]

If you have not Studio but have installed the SDK, you should look where this installed, find the SDK folder, copy this address and puts it in the Unity preferences> External Tools> SDK.